# Programmatically remove app and email accounts in Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, authentication

I am working in an organization with shared PC's and the issue is the users are signing into Office apps and the apps are adding the users accounts to the device.  Which is a bit of a security concern.

I was wondering if there is a way to remove these accounts programmatically using powershell / c# library / registry setting (maybe some unknown WMI class).  Searching for one seems to be a dead end.

Any pointers / thoughts in the right direction would be appreciated.

[Example of accounts in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6wjY.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! TBH, this isn't the right place to ask this; we're supposed to fix already-sort-of-working code. If you could write the part that detects what accounts need to be deleted and when, this would be a much better question.

Comment: Maybe research over on https://superuser.com/ This feels like a bit of an "X-Y" question. The solution probably has more to do with how you setup your domain users during authentication, rather than some hack that blows away accounts.